# Relations notation

Tags: notation

say, you have $R^* :== \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty}R^k$, where $R$ relation and $R^n =R^{n-1}R$.

Then $(R^*)^* = (\bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty}R^k)^* = $ ??

I am not sure about how to open the second $*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$
(R^*)^* 
= \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty} (R^*)^k 
= \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty} ( \bigcup_{l=0}^{\infty} R^l ){}^k 
$$

Now (can you see and show this?),
$$( \bigcup_{l=0}^{\infty} R^l )^k = \bigcup_{l=0}^{\infty} R^{lk}$$
so$$
(R^*)^* 
= \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty} (R^*)^k 
= \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{l=0}^{\infty} R^{lk}
= \bigcup_{n = 0}^{\infty} R^{n}
= R^*
$$
where the reduction from two unions to one union is valid since $lk$ runs over all natural numbers.

Comment: And, what that could mean? The union of all $R^l$-s is a one set. What is the union over all $k$-s over one set?

Comment: I've expanded my answer after getting an insight into what happens.